# How to calculate set product quantity from subproduct quantity?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 tables:
The first have product code set, subproduct code and the corresponding quantity. The second is containing quantity in stock of each subproduct code:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [
['MHA601', 'A1: 1 | A2: 4'],
['MHA602', 'A1: 1 | A2: 6'],
['MHB502', 'B1: 1 | B2: 1 | B3: 1']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Product_code_set','Subproduct_code'])
data2 = [
['A1', 2],
['A2', 8],
['B1', 1],
['B2', 0],
['B3', 1]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Subproduct_code','Quantity'])

# How do i create a table containing the quantity of products set:
data3 = [
['MHA601', 2],
['MHA602', 1],
['MHB502', 0]]
result = pd.DataFrame(data3 , columns=['Product_code_set','Quantity'])
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: your dataframes are not valid python, can you please fix it?

Comment: Can you explain your output with calculation?

Comment: The calculation of the set product quantity is based on the number of subproduct in df2 and the minimum number of subproduct in df1. And NO need to consider the sharing of sub-product codes quantity between set product codes like 'MHA601' & 'MHA602'.

Comment: still unclear. If you had 2 A1 and 8 A2 in df2, then you would have `[2, 1, 0]`?

Comment: @mozway yes, it is correct!

Comment: I changed to 2/8 as I believe this will be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `extract` the codes/values, `div`ide the reference quantity and get the `min` integer value per group:

```
extract = df1['Subproduct_code'].str.extractall('(?P<code>[\w]+): (?P<qty>\d+)')

s = df2.set_index('Subproduct_code')['Quantity']

df1['quantity'] = (extract['code'].map(s)
 .div(extract['qty'].astype(int))
 .astype(int)
 .groupby(level=0).min()
)
```

output:

```
  Product_code_set        Subproduct_code  quantity
0           MHA601          A1: 1 | A2: 4         2
1           MHA602          A1: 1 | A2: 6         1
2           MHB502  B1: 1 | B2: 1 | B3: 1         0
```

intermediates:

```
# extract
        code qty
  match         
0 0       A1   1
  1       A2   4
1 0       A1   1
  1       A2   6
2 0       B1   1
  1       B2   1
  2       B3   1

# s
Subproduct_code
A1    2
A2    8
B1    1
B2    0
B3    1
Name: Quantity, dtype: int64

# (extract['code'].map(s)
#  .div(extract['qty'].astype(int))
# )
   match
0  0        2.000000
   1        2.000000
1  0        2.000000
   1        1.333333
2  0        1.000000
   1        0.000000
   2        1.000000
dtype: float64
```